# Add a root node and child to root node to XML using XSLT as well as output transformed xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to add two nodes to the outside of some xml and output the transformed result to an xml file. I have not been able to get it to work. My xml would be:

```
<message>
    <!-- ...other nodes and elements in here, not always consistent -->
</message>
```

(EDIT)Expected XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rootNode>
    <submessage>
        <message>
           <!-- ...other nodes and elements in here, not always consistent -->
        </message>
    </submessage>
</rootNode>
```

Below is the xsl that I have tried but does not seem to work. Any ideas on what I should do to add the two nodes 'rootNode' and 'submessage' and output the results?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">    
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />
    <xsl:variable name="root" select="/" />
    <xsl:variable name="filename" select="'testOutPut'" />

<xsl:template match="/">        
    <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}.xml" method="xml">
        <rootNode>
            <submessage>
                <message>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </message>
            </submessage>
        </rootNode>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DefaultNodes/*">       
    <xsl:variable name="sourceNode" select="$root/message/*[name() = name(current())]" />
    <xsl:choose>            
        <xsl:when test="$sourceNode">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$sourceNode" />
        </xsl:when>            
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:otherwise>            
    </xsl:choose>       
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/rootNode">
    <Request xmlns="urn:NameSpace-Definition-Message" 
        xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">             
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>           
    </Request>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: Also, I am a quite green at xsl transforms, this is my first attempt and am trying to possibly use this as a solution to editing/doctoring some xml before it gets consumed.

Comment: Am I right that you try, in a single transformation to: 1) Output a first transformation to an external XML file (and surround your document with 2 extra elements) 2) Transform this XML file to something else ? I ask because I see that you create `rootNode` (= it's not in your source XML) and have a template that matches it.

Comment: @ColinMaudry The outputting of the document was just to be able to see if my tranform worked. In my actual scenario I need to just add the two outer nodes to the xml. I will add an expected xml block to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it looks like that you are trying to achieve is what is called a (micro-)pipeline. It is not possible to output a result document and to read it back in in a single transformation (for reasons of determinism of the language), but it is very well possible to do a transformation on your intermediate output by re-applying it:

Replace this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">        
    <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}.xml" method="xml">
        <rootNode>
            <submessage>
                <message>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </message>
            </submessage>
        </rootNode>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

With something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">        
    <xslvariable name="intermediate">
        <rootNode>
            <submessage>
                <message>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </message>
            </submessage>
        </rootNode>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}.xml" method="xml">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$intermediate/*" mode="second" />
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

You probably want to switch modes on your second apply-templates (`second` in my example), and place the template matching `/rootNode` and anything following in this new mode.

### Edit (based on your comment)

It appears, from your comment, that all you want to do is take some input XML and add two elements surrounding that input XML. The best starting point is to use an identity transform:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- there is no need to use xsl:result-document if you only 
         want one output document, otherwise, add it back here -->
    <rootNode>
        <submessage>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </submessage>
    </rootNode>
</xsl:template>

<!-- generically and recursively match and copy any node, incl. attribs -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- make sure to process any children -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that I removed `<message>`, because that appears to be in you input document already and will be copied anyway.

Also, same as my original answer, there will be no match with `/rootNode`, unless you do a micro-pipeline, because it does not exist in your original input. The above code will work. If you add any template to it with a more specific match, you can override that element. If you also want to process its children, make sure to add an `xsl:apply-templates`.

For instance, suppose you want to change the element `foo` into `bar`, you can do this (just add the template to the identity transform):

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
    <bar>
        <!-- process children, child text nodes, attributes etc -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </bar>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I should have probably made it clear, but I was only wanting to output the xml to a file so I could test my changes and make tweaks as needed. My main goal is just to transform the xml by adding the two outer nodes as indicated in the question. I have updated the question to show what I am expected xml wise.

Comment: @Popo: I updated the answer to show you to do just that: surround the input with some elements.